# Read XML file by Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, apache, flask

I created web application by Flask. And I read data from xml file by javascript. It is run fantastic but when I deployed my flask application on apache I have a problem with read current data. If I change some data in xml file on apache I can see only old data. Nothing happens. Data on webpage change only when I restart apache server. What is wrong ? I try many possibilites how to parse XML data for example ajax.

```
 function ReadTemperatureFromxXML() {
    var xmlDoc;
    var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        if (!xmlDoc) {
            xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, 'text/xml');
            var emp = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temperature");
            var temperature1 = emp[0].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].firstChild.data;
            temperature1 = temperature1.concat("°C")
            document.getElementById("temperature1").innerHTML = temperature1;
            ....
}
```

Code for ajax reading

```
  /*  $.ajax({
   url: 'data.xml',
   dataType:  'xml',
   success: function(data){
       $(data).find('data temperature').each(function()
       {
         var temperature = $(this).find('value').text();
         $('.timeline').append(
                 $('<li />',{
                     text: temperature
                 })
         );

       });

   },
   error: function() {
       $('.timeline').text('Failed to get')
   }
```

})
*/

Settings apache server

```
WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp user=pi group=www-data threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/Kotelna/kotelna.wsgi
  <Directory /home/pi/Kotelna>
     WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
     WSGIScriptReloading On
     WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
     Require all granted
  </Directory>
Alias /static/ /home/pi/Kotelna/static/
  <Directory /home/pi/Kotelna/static/>
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

when you mouse over")!
This works with [reference links](https://stackoverflow.blog/) as well.

```
   Errorlog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

By my web browser i looked to network and I can see reguest of xml file.
Error list of console is clear as same as Error log file apache. 
I try change apache2.conf like this

```
<Directory />
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

It is posible fix this problem ? Or is there any other way how to read xml file ? Thank you for reply.

Comment: You're not using AJAX correctly, you have to wait for the response, at the point when you're accessing the response `var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;`, `xmlhttp.responseXML` is `undefined`. You can learn more about AJAX from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 0):

Yes maybe I using Ajax incorrectly, but it is work very well. My problem is in flask because I need reload my data.xml..... before I use this command

```
@app.route('/data.xml')
    def data():    
return render_template('/data.xml')
```

Now I use

```
@app.route('/data.xml')
def data():
return send_from_directory("templates", "data.xml")
```

it is reload only my xml file only if I go to localhost/data.xml
Is there any other command?, which solving my problem. Something some autoreloadig by time. Thank you for you reply